# How to create dictionary within list

Tags: c#, list, class, dictionary, object

I have a class **Mobile** in which my dictionary is declared. I have another class **Cell** through which I want to call this dictionary and add items into it. I have created a function in the **Mobile** class to add elements into the dictionary. My two classes are.

```
public class Mobile {

   public Dictionary<string, Mobile> dict;
   
   
   public Mobile(int x,int y) {
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    dict = new Dictionary<string, Mobile>();
   }
   
   pulic void Add_data_to_dictionary(string a,Mobile b)
   {
   this.dict.Add(a,b);
   }
 
}

public class Cell
{
Mobile x=new Mobile():

}
```

I need to implement my code in Cell class. My problem is that I have to create a list of **nodes** of class **Mobile** where each node must contain a **dictionary** and each dictionary should have multiple **key-value** pairs.

Hierarchy is like this

```
node1->dictionary[key1,val1,key2,val2] 
node2->dictionary[key1,val1,key2,val2] 
node3->dictionary[key1,val1,key2,val2]
```

can anyone help me how do I do that?

Comment: What is your nodes? You want `List<Cell>` or `List<Mobile>`? Also your dictionary in `Mobile` class is `private`, so you can add `KeyValuePair`s to it through `Add_data_to_dictionary` method, but can not read data from it.

Comment: what are `a`,`b`,`x`, & `y`  in your code? Theyrenot defined anywhere at all.

Comment: @Auditive my nodes are list<Mobile>. Also i can make it public. no problem with that

Comment: @Jamiec x and y are just two other variables that is not in the scope of this question but are present in the contructor where dictionary called. a and b are dictionary elements where a is a string and b is class object. I just wanted to know the structure for dictionary within list that's why i didn't explain their presence

Comment: ok so surely the answer is just you want `this.dict.Add(a,b);` - I don't see what the problem is here you're trying to solve?!

Comment: @Jamiec i'm sorry my bad. I just edited my question. I'm actually doing it in my ```Add_data_to_dictionary``` function. I am doing it. every time I call this function will it create a new dictionary?and how do I save dictionary with multiple key/value pairs in my list index. List index is of class Mobile as i just told you

Comment: In your example new dictionary creates only when you initializing (creating) `Mobile` object. `public void Add_data_to_dictionary` only adds key and value to it.

Comment: Okay I get it thank you. do you know solution regarding put that dictionary in a list?

Comment: I still can't figure out what you trying to achieve. Let's try again. You need list of Mobiles? or List of each Mobile dictionaries? Or List of each Mobile dictionary keyvaluepairs? Or List of each Mobile dictionary only keys or values?

Comment: I need a **List of class Mobile**. At each index of List, I need **One Dictionary of class Mobile** where each dictionary can have many entries of key,value pairs. Did I make it clear now? I need to do all of it from within ```Cell``` class

Comment: So give `Cell` a `List<Mobile>` which you can access by index. `Mobile` has a dictionary within it already. You seem to have all the building blocks here but just not sure how to put it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you trying to achieve, but as you said:

> I need a List of class Mobile. At each index of List, I need One
> Dictionary of class Mobile where each dictionary can have many entries
> of key,value pairs.

It could be done probably in that way:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize List of your Mobiles
        List<Mobile> mobiles = new List<Mobile>();

        // Fill list in some way
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            // Create new Mobile
            Mobile mobile = new Mobile();

            // Add data to its Dictionary
            mobile.AddDataToDictionary("SomeKey #" + i, mobile); // Add itself as value?!

            // Add to list of Mobiles (your nodes)
            mobiles.Add(mobile);
        }

        // Create Cell instance and pass list of Mobiles to it
        Cell cell = new Cell(mobiles);
        // Do what you want with mobiles there
        cell.DoWorkWithMobiles();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


public class Mobile
{
    // Make Dictionary as public property to grant access to it for read purposes
    public Dictionary<string, Mobile> Dict { get; private set; }

    // I removed arguments x/y for this example
    public Mobile()
    {
        Dict = new Dictionary<string, Mobile>();
    }

    public void AddDataToDictionary(string key, Mobile value)
    {
        Dict.Add(key, value);
    }
}

public class Cell
{
    // To store list, which was passed to class constructor
    private List<Mobile> mobiles;

    public Cell(List<Mobile> mobiles)
    {
        this.mobiles = mobiles;
    }

    public void DoWorkWithMobiles()
    {
        // Very unclear what to do here
        for (int i = 0; i < mobiles.Count; i++)
        {
            Mobile mobile = mobiles[i];
            Mobile mobileFromDict = mobile.Dict["SomeKey #" + i];
            //or 
            mobile.Dict.TryGetValue("SomeKey #" + i, out Mobile mob);
            Mobile m = mob.Dict["SomeKey #" + i];
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, an architecture and logic of your project isn't clear and example may be incorrect and stupid.